# Charged particle interacting with electromagnetism and gravity

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, point-particles

Consider a classically charged point particle interacting with electromagnetism and gravity. The relevant dynamical variables are $\chi^\mu (\tau)$ of the particle, the electromangetic potential $A_\mu (x)$, and the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$. The action is:

$ S=-\int d^{4}x\sqrt {-g}\left[\dfrac {1} {2 \kappa} R+\dfrac{1}{4}g^{\alpha \gamma} g^{\beta \delta} F_{\alpha \beta} F_{\gamma \delta}\right]-\int d\tau \left[m_o\sqrt {g_{\alpha \beta}[\chi]\dot{\chi}^\alpha\dot{\chi}^\beta}+e\dot{\chi}^\mu A_\mu[\chi]\right]$

where $\kappa=8\pi G$, $m_o$ is the mass of the point particle, and e is its charge. We wish to calculate the self energy of the point particle. Therefore we take:

$\chi^i(0)=0\qquad \dot{\chi}^i(0)=0 $

$A_i(0,\boldsymbol{x})=0 \qquad E^i(0,\boldsymbol{x})\equiv \sqrt{-g}F^{i0}=-\partial_i \phi$

$g_{ij}(0,\boldsymbol{x})=-\psi^{(4)}(\boldsymbol x)\delta_{ij} \qquad\pi^{ij}(0,\boldsymbol{x})=0 $

Question: Why are the above initial conditions on the dynamical variables and their conjugate momenta the correct ones for our physical problem?

Comment: The initial conditions correspond to the "rest frame" of the particle (first row) in accordingly static isotropical coordinates (third row). The second row corresponds to a particular gauge and the requirement that there are no electromagnetic waves which obviously interact with the particle.